# How to install Saxon or Saxon-HE with apt or snap?

Tags: apt, java, snap, libraries, xml

How do I install `saxon` so that it's [reasonably](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65128003/4531180) up to date?

```
The file will be called saxon-he-10.0.jar for Saxon Home Edition, saxon-pe-10.0.jar for the Professional Edition, or saxon-ee-10.0.jar for the Enterprise Edition (where the "10.0" in the name will change to "10.1", "10.2", etc. in subsequent maintenance releases):
```

https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/about/gettingstarted/gettingstartedjava.html

Just seems like quite a leap from 6.x to 10.x, so would I be wrong in assuming there's a way to install a more updated version with `apt`?  Perhaps the `libxslt` package on `snap` has a more recent version:

```
nicholas@mordor:~/xml$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/xml$ snap find saxon
Name     Version          Publisher  Notes  Summary
libxslt  1.1.33+pkg-213d  brlin      -      XSLT C library developed for the GNOME project
nicholas@mordor:~/xml$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/xml$ snap info libxslt
name:      libxslt
summary:   XSLT C library developed for the GNOME project
publisher: 林博仁(Buo-ren, Lin) (brlin)
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/libxslt
contact:   https://github.com/Lin-Buo-Ren/libxslt-snap/issues
license:   MIT
description: |
  Libxslt is the XSLT C library developed for the GNOME project. XSLT itself is a an XML language to
  define transformation for XML. Libxslt is based on libxml2 the XML C library developed for the
  GNOME project. It also implements most of the EXSLT set of processor-portable extensions functions
  and some of Saxon's evaluate and expressions extensions.
  
  People can either embed the library in their application or use xsltproc the command line
  processing tool. This library is free software and can be reused in commercial applications.
  
  This is NOT an official distribution of libxslt, for any issue regarding using this snap please
  refer to the issue tracker:
  
      https://github.com/Lin-Buo-Ren/libxslt-snap/issues
snap-id: AZt5N0Bbo3oTTGDSg6F1pcfybcSzChps
channels:
  latest/stable:    1.1.33+pkg-213d             2019-07-20 (67) 10MB -
  latest/candidate: ↑                                                
  latest/beta:      ↑                                                
  latest/edge:      1.1.33-49-g15edbe4+pkg-01d2 2019-07-20 (73) 10MB -
nicholas@mordor:~/xml$
```

Obviously, version 10 can just be manually downloaded, but, again, that's quite a lag from v6 to v10.  Hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for Saxon/C or Saxon/J?

On Java, most people with this requirement use Maven for the open source edition. We don't currently publish on Maven for the commercial products, because of concerns about licensing, but we've got plans to change that.

For Saxon/C, it's currently a manual installation. Again, we're trying to improve the installability of the product but it's more complex because of the large number of different platform combinations.

I'm not sure of the relevance of libxslt.